# Creating list and sublists in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of activities category that each activity in this list would be itself will be categorized and again each of this final activities link me to a specific number that I use that number in a function at Excel to find out my final answer.

I'm looking for a solution to make this automated so when some one select their particular activity then they need to choose its sub-activities related to their choice (without displaying other activities) will be loaded and when they picked the one I will receive the specific code or number for that activity. 
Also I do not know how can I define number for a text cell that when I select it gives me the number or code that has been defined for it.

Example: I'm asking you select what you do during a week regard to workout and physical activity. you select the cell and choose for example bicycling and then you will be asked to be more specific, and you select another cell to choose ''biking 4mph to 7 mph''.

The answers would be a number and that number will be placed in function in another cell and gives me the calorie that you burn during that specific activity.

How can I create this formula? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  I suggest you read the HELP pages for information as to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Then reword your question to fit in with those guidelines by editing your original question.

Comment: You should be able to archive via drop-down list and If formula, but it is hard to give you an answer without sample data and an example.

Comment: I have a list of activities category let’s call it “A” that for example included “A1 TO A10”. Each activity in this list would be itself categorized let’s say Activity ‘’A1’’ will be sub listed to “A11 TO A19’’ and again each of this activities has been defined by a specific number. (LIST ‘’A’’ and it’s sub list are Text format. Finally i will get a number from your answer and that number will be placed in a function. There is over 800 activities in total but there is list of 10 to 15 which each will be categorized to 20 to 30 activities and each activities has it’s own specific number.

Comment: Ex. I'm asking you select what you do during a week regard to workout and physical activity?
You select the cell and choose for example ‘’A1’’ from “A1 to A10” and then you will be asked to be more specific, and you select another cell to choose ''A12'' FROM ‘’A11 TO A19’’. The particular answer would be a number how ever and that number will be placed in function in another cell and gives me the calorie that you burn during that specific activity.

Comment: I'M SORRY , you are right. i hope you understand better my point. i can not find any example . but it looks like more a calculator to estimate your calorie expenditure during an specific activity. i have all the information but it's hard to make this questionarie automated or like a calculator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to create a cascading dropdown list. I have included a link to a website that explains how to make a cascading dropdown list which is what I think you are looking for. let me know if this does not answer your question.

[Cascading Dropdown Link](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/09/30/dependent-cascading-dropdown-lists-excel/)

**Edit:**

I am adding a image to an example I created in Excel. The formula i used in the data validation box was:

```
=IF($A$1=$F$2,$G$2:$G$5,IF($A$1=$F$3,$H$2:$H$5,IF($A$1=$F$4,$I$2:$I$5,$J$2)))
```

**Edit 2:**

Based on the additional information in the comments you provided, I created the pictured excel workbook.

[VLookup Example Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIRTv.png)

The top of the image shows the excel values. The bottom of the image is expanded to show the formulas in each cell.

These formulas should allow you to get the value you wanted by looking it up based on what you enter into the previous cells in the form. In my case, when you change the values in cell A11 and A12 you will see cells C11 and C12 change to the correct values. **If you combine this with my first answer you can get drop down menu's working as well.**

let me know if you need any other explanation.

Comment: Thank you @robert-boyett so much for the time to help me. appreciate it. i understood exactly what you mentioned here but this was not I meant. let me i use your example to express myself better. in Column A , A1 TO A3 we have (eg. running, biking and swimming). in column B , C and D we have their sub categories (eg. B1:B3 running uphill, running on beach and running with 4 to 5 mph. C1:C3 is a number shows the impact factor for this specific activity eg 2, 3, 4 .

Comment: . D1:D3 listed as biking type 1, type and type 3. E1:E3 again the impact factors as a number. F1:F3 swimming type 1, type 2 and type 3. G1:G3 impact factor for Swimming types). what I'm trying to create for users is asking them select their activity category first which would be either running, swimming or biking. when they select one from this list A1:A3 so next question would be their choice from the sub categories. let's say they select A2 (eg. running) well they have to select only one from B1:B3.

Comment: Let’s say B2. B2 is text contents and the impact factor next to it is Number format. 
I need that number to use the function that I already have to find out how much calorie they will burn.

Comment: I read the dynamic drop List and whole day was working on it, but i think i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: check my new edit for my answer. It contains my work up of your examples you have given. let me know if you need more help.

Comment: thanks, here is what i did and work but there is minor isuue. My Goodness! it took me my whole day! First i picked a name for my main activity category (there is almost 10 activities and each one sub categorized between 10 to 40, total over 800 activities) and i call it ''mainlist'' then i picked a name for each sub categories. based on the Link that you send me regard to "dependent drop down list". i was able to create one with ''indirect'' function and data validation. then i used ''vlookup'' function for sub categories by defining a name. How? i entered all sub activities

Comment: in one column (almost all 800 activities) and their impact factor in next column. then i used this command " =VLOOKUP(B2,MET,2,FALSE)'' which ''MET'' is the name i defined for all subcategories in column 1 and 2 is column 2. i can get the answer but the PROBLEM is , it does not give me automated answer. i mean when i select the category and the sub category , it does not give me an automated answer in look up cell. i have to click on check box to give me the new number! i do not know may be because it is dependent drop down list and i need to find make the third column dependent too!!

Comment: Does "MET" include both columns of data? meaning does it include the column with the item you are looking up and the column with the answer you are expecting?

Comment: Yes i did and it works but i do not know when i changed the cell's value or contents but VLookUp Function does not work automatically . i have to click on function or check box in function tab to give me the answer. is there any function or the way I can make it automated by changing the data's? I appreciate it thank you so much

Comment: It works automatically for me. When you change the selections, press F9 and tell me if that updates your vlookup cells.

Comment: I found out , yesssss! the problem was in formulas tab, there is an option calculate now. so when you click on options there is asking manual or automatic . mine in my new sheet was manual. i fixed it and now it's working. awesome. thanks Robert you are such an awesome dude.

Comment: Thanks for the update. If my answer worked for you would you mind marking it as the correct answer? I am working on building up my reputation around here and that would help me out.

Comment: Are you familiar with multiple condition if function? how should I create up to 10 Condition in if?

Comment: the normal =IF() function can only be nested up to 7 times in one formula. Depending on your version of Excel, you may have a =IFS() formula which can be used to test up to 127 conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I have built something very similar to what you are describing for my own work purposes. I believe you will be presenting this document to other users, (i.e. staff, clients, etc.) so I will suggest moving your categorized responses to a separate sheet. This way you will have a very clean, presentable worksheet as a presentation layer.

Let me use your example provided in the comments, however I will add a mapping. the first category has options in cells A1:A3 (eg. running, biking, and swimming). B1:B5 has speeds for running, C1:C5 has speeds for biking, and D1:D5 has speeds for swimming (i.e. 1mph, 2mph, 3mph, 4mph, 5mph).

Next, lets reserve a column in order to return a column letter (in the eg. column B, C, or D should be returned depending on the workout selection). in column E, type the following, and copy down for all rows where data will be selected: =IFERROR(INDEX({"B","C","D"},MATCH(A1,$A$1:$A$3,0)),"B") << the "B" at the end is to prevent errors from returning on cells with no data selected.

In your cell where you want the type of exercise to be selected (I will choose cell F1), add a data validation (2010 & later: in the "Data" tab in the ribbon). Select "List" in the first dropdown and the Source (given the example I provided above) would display the following: "$A$1:$A$3".

Then, in cell G1 (for my eg), repeat the data validation process however type the following into the Source: =INDIRECT(E1&"1:"&E1&"5",1)

INDIRECT will build the data validation list for you however you MUST include the intermediary step I provided in column E as you cannot include arrays in a data validation list. please also copy all formulas down to include every row you want to dedicate to this functionality (if you don't see the little arrow on the cell when you select it, the formula does not exist in that cell, therefore copy it down)

if you list of workouts goes beyond 3 (I imagine so), expand your data validation list in cell F1 to include all workouts (in your example, put "$A$1:$A$10" (no quotes)). If you list of (in the example provided) speeds increases beyond 5 levels, in the INDIRECT formula located in your G1 data validation cell, change the "5" to include all rows. If your example, if the speeds where located in cells A11:A19, you would type this instead: =INDIRECT(E1&"11:"&E1&"19",1)

You can repeat the process as many times as you like however for every level deeper you include, you must replicate the process in column E as this will be the column that tells the subsequent levels where to look.

Let me know if you require further description on how to code the deeper levels (i.e. biking, 15 mph, 20 mins, 7 intensity << this is three levels deep)

**EDIT**

**Additional step below**

My apologies for not having included something of that nature. You can still use the method I described above in order to create dynamic drop down lists however you do need an additional step in order to return the value that represents the intensity level to be calculated against the calorie count constant.

I must say +1 for Robert Boyett's answer. It is the easier way to code what you need. I will provide a method that will allow you to dynamically add more workout routines as you see fit without having to add additional IF conditions and associated VLOOKUPs. I will use Robert Boyett's link as a reference.

In cell C11, type the following: =SUMIFS(INDIRECT(INDEX({"A","B","C","D","E","F","G"},MATCH(A11,$A$4:$G$4,0)+1)&"1:"&INDEX({"A","B","C","D","E","F","G"},MATCH(A11,$A$4:$G$4,0)+1)&"3"),INDIRECT(INDEX({"A","B","C","D","E","F","G"},MATCH(A11,$A$4:$G$4,0))&"1:"&INDEX({"A","B","C","D","E","F","G"},MATCH(A11,$A$4:$G$4,0))&"3"),B11)

This will require cells B4, D4, and F4 to drop the tailing " Type" and instead match exactly with the wording from your first drop down list (Running, Biking, Swimming), this way the MATCH formula will return the required value.

You may also expand the limit in the MATCH formula ($A$4:$G$4) to a long ways away... say $A$4:$BA$4 << this will allow up to 26 different workouts. Expand further to include more workout types. Also, in the INDIRECT formula, expand the "3" to a large number in order to include more intensity levels (putting "9" instead of "3" will allow up to 9 intensity levels).

You may have noticed I include an array with the alphabet. It is better practice to have this array actually select a series of cells that, in each subsequent cell, contains each letter of the alphabet. in my example of using a range of $A$4:$BA$4, you would put in, say, column BB, the alphabet in each row, and when you reach Z, restart the alphabet with a leading A (i.e. AA, AB, AC, etc.) and continue as far as you like. Replace the array (identified with the curly brackets {} inside the INDEX formula) with this range, in this example, $BB$1:$BB$53.

Also, I would suggest putting the headers in the top row, so instead of $A$4:$G$4 (or in the last paragraph $A$4:$BA$4) you should have $A$1:$BA$1. this way you can add as many level intensities as you like (provided you allotted as such in the INDIRECT function.

After all my direction provided after the initial formula, you will now have in cell C17: =SUMIFS(INDIRECT(INDEX($BB$1:BB$53,MATCH(A11,$A$1:$BA$1,0)+1)&"1:"&INDEX($BB$1:BB$53,MATCH(A11,$A$1:$BA$1,0)+1)&"9"),INDIRECT(INDEX($BB$1:BB$53,MATCH(A11,$A$1:$BA$1,0))&"1:"&INDEX($BB$1:BB$53,MATCH(A11,$A$1:$BA$1,0))&"9"),B11)

Increase the limits as you see fit. I would heavily suggest putting the data into a separate spreadsheet or, if running an older version of Excel, cut and paste this data to the right of your userform (say right of column H looks safe as per Robert's pic) and hide the columns. Then protect the sheet from alteration, less the cells you chose to unprotect for user input.

Cheers Robert Boyett for supplying the .png files on your hosted server. Very helpful resource.

Comment: Thank you so much for the time to demonstrate by an example. i understand what you exactly said here but this was not I meant. let me i use your example to express my self better. in Column A , A1 TO A3 we have (eg. running, biking and swimming).

Comment: in column B , C and D we have their sub categories (eg. B1:B3 running uphill, running on beach and running with 4 to 5 mph. C1:C3 is a number shows the impact factor for this specific activity eg 2, 3, 4 . D1:D3 listed as biking type 1, type and type 3. E1:E3 again the impact factors as a number.

Comment: F1:F3 swimming type 1, type 2 and type 3. G1:G3 impact factor for Swimming types). what I'm trying to create for users is asking them select their activity category first which would be either running, swimming or biking. when they select one from this list A1:A3 so next question would be their choice from the sub categories. let's say they select A2 (eg. running) well they have to select only one from B1:B3.

Comment: Let’s say B2. B2 is text contents and the impact factor next to it is Number format. 
I need that number to use the function that I already have to find out how much calorie they will burn.